# Android TextView text not updating but color updating

Tags: android, textview

On a button click I want to set textview with a value zero.But the textview in not updation but I can set the text color.I have tried some solution like postdelayed and runOnUIThread  but no change is there.I have used Tab in my application and the problem appears when I go to another tab and again come back to this activity.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

```
public void Delete(View view) {

    time.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    time.setText("0");
    time.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

}

 <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/delete_sound"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/dummyString"
                    android:onClick="Delete" />
```

Comment: We need to see more code. What is `time`? Where do you call this method? Etc.

Comment: Remove the settextcolor and see it is working or not.

Comment: @KenWolf time is the name of textview and Delete is method executing on button click

Comment: Why are you passing in `View view` and then not using it at all?

Comment: @Aravinth I have added settextcolor to check whether it is working or not.without settextcolor also it will not work

Comment: @KenWolf the metod is specified in the xml and the view not using

Comment: Are you actually calling `setText("0")` exactly like that?

Comment: @KenWolf Yes.of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. it is working fine for me

```
    (findViewById(R.id.btnchange)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            TextView time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Your_Textview_ID);
            time.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            time.setText("0");
            time.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Declare button's click event in java file rather than in xml

Comment: Done.It sets zero for a second  then again set to previous value

Comment: Yes textview is reinitialized before setting the value as in your code

Comment: your textview's value is reinitialized after button click

Comment: Yes you are right.Thank you so much.There is TimerTask which sets the Textview.

Answer (score 0):

**try by Re-initializing inside**  `Delete()`

```
public void Delete(View view) {
        TextView time=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
        time.setText("0");
    }
```

Edit **or Try** following in your `onCreate()`

```
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.delete_sound);
        ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Delete(v);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't want to set the color.I just want to set the text

Comment: why this android:onClick="**Delete"** instead of android:onClick="Delete" ?

Comment: Please check now. I have tried ti bold the Delete for getting your attention and it appears with star